# How to trigger wordpress / woocommerce email on payment gateway plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have made a wordpress plugin. It handles a new payment gateway with credit card. After the succesfull transaction I close the order but cannot send email. I tried everything. I tried to call the mailer on init, but it fails on error.log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_order_number() on
>   boolean in
>   ....../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-processing-order.php
>   on line 58

I tried to make a `new WC_simplepay();` on init, it fails with class not found.

I tried the same mail sending in the class with new function, and call it from the constructor with `$this->functionname();` It works, mail sent, but the payment provider (or me) cannot call this from url (this is why I check the request param), because the class only loads when you are in the checkout page.

I tried the global `$woocommerce` ... etc solution but also not working in the init part, only inside the class.

Starting of the plugin code:

```
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_simplepay_init', 0);

    function woocommerce_simplepay_init(){
        if(!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) return;

        if ($_REQUEST['REFNOEXT']!='')
        {
            /* .... here are some code regarding the gateway provider ,logging, etc... fully working */
            $order_id = explode('_',$_REQUEST['REFNOEXT']);
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id[0]);
            $order->update_status('processing');
            WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger($order_id[0]); // this is generating the error
        }

    class WC_simplepay extends WC_Payment_Gateway{

        public function __construct(){
...
```

So basically how can I close the order, send email to the customer and handle the provider thingies with this class using remote URL calls?

Answer (score 0):

You are hooking into the wrong action, I recommend you to hook on `init` because it's executed after all plugins (including woocommerce) has been loaded.

```
add_action('init', 'woocommerce_simplepay_init');

function woocommerce_simplepay_init(){
    if(!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) return;

    if ($_REQUEST['REFNOEXT']!='')
    {
        $order_id = explode('_',$_REQUEST['REFNOEXT']);
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id[0]);
        $order->update_status('processing');
        WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger($order_id[0]); // this is generating the error
    }
```

But since you're using a Class, I believe that's better to include this function inside a class.

[Init hook reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the provider call our site with http://domain.com/?REFNOEXT=samevalue
And the hook only fires when payment complete. i need to close the order and send mail when they call it after payment. It happens in the background.

Comment: So, you wanna do it in the confirmation page? or in any page?

Comment: In any page. I have to set this url on the provider admin. Then they can call this url with post data when the transaction is complete. It happens about in a minute after the user payment on the site.

Comment: The hook is fired, but fails. PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_order_number() on boolean in .../plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-processing-order.php on line 58

Comment: check the updated answer, I have changed the hook and explanation. This should work for you.